# What is the ldf file, what does that file contain in a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the `.ldf` file? What does it contain? How to see practically in `.ldf` file?

Comment: If you don't know what is in it, why would you want to look in one, practically or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

LDF is a file extension for a log file used with Microsoft SQL Server. LDF files contain logging information for all transactions completed by the server. LDF files are used to time stamp any transactions to the SQL Server database, allowing the SQL database to be easily recoverable in the case of data loss

from this link you will find about .ldf  https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/open-ldf-file-and-view-ldf-file-content/